# Why checked property in css is not working in IE-7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I am using some thing like this in css

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label { color:#121212 }
```

the problem is this the checked property is not working in Internet-Explorer-8 and 7.

ifI use like this

```
input[type=radio] + label { color:$888888 }
```

its working properly

Please tell me alternate of this

Comment: [Because it's not supported...](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t33)

Comment: you have to search in google first. It's a CSS3 property

Comment: any body tell me alternative of this

Comment: It's not even a property. It's a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use http://selectivizr.com/ JS. It's support css3 selector in older version of IE.

Answer (score 2):

The pseudo-class :checked is not supported in IE 7.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked

Answer (score 0):

That is a pseudo-class.
pseudo-class is currently not supported in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Pseudo-classes aren't a new thing, you know. IE has been supporting pseudo-classes since the very beginning, just not all of them. And pseudo-classes are selectors, not properties.

Comment: Sorry...I forgot to specify that, I told about this pseudo-class.
Sorry for that!