# Why does this CSS selector not work in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, css-selectors, prototypejs

I have this Prototype JS code:

```
$$('#someid input[type=radio]:checked + span.label + div > span')[0];
```

I noticed that IE 10 (and maybe the version below, too) do not manage to find the element selected by the above code. Its because of the :checked. Removing it, makes it work, but thats not what I need. I searched the net and figured that IE supports the :checked selector, so whats the problem?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: which library are you using? jQuery?

Comment: I am using Prototype JS

Comment: The browser's CSS support is irrelevent. The question should be "does Prototype support the checked selector"?

Comment: Sure it does, the same code works in FF and Chrome...

Comment: perhaps this question and its answers still apply?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927129/why-checked-property-in-css-is-not-working-in-ie-7

Comment: Nope, unfortunaltely it doesnt ... in IE 10 and IE 9 it is supported. I dont want to install any additional libs, since it should work out of the box.

Comment: Just tested $$('input[type=radio]:checked'); on <input type="radio" checked /> with prototype 1.7.1 in IE10 and it did return array with that input, seems that :checked alone isnt the cause of your problem

Comment: would you post the html containing the input in question?

Comment: The browser is irrelevant as PrototypeJS uses the Sizzle CSS engine to find elements (which is the same engine as jQuery). I checked this in http://jsfiddle.net/Jg6BQ/ and it returns the last span element - is that the element you need?