# Other ways to write css to checked checkbox?

Tags: css

Pls help. this CSS is not functioning once I uncheck/check. it just retains default load value.

```
input[type="checkbox"][checked] + label{}
```

This one is fine but, i found it weird that its not functioning on IE

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label
```

Comment: `input[type="checkbox"][checked]` will work when you have `checked` attribute declared, where as the other one will work when the checkbox is checked, and it should work in IE, make sure your `label` is adjacent to `checkbox`

Comment: The :checked pseudo-class is only available since IE9 per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127296(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10927129/why-checked-property-in-css-is-not-working-in-ie-7) for suggestions to overcome IE issues

Comment: @diceyyyy please accept/upvote the answer if it answers and help your question. We really put some effort to answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try below css :

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  background-color: red;  
}
```

Comment: this is correct. but I need to edit the label next to the checkbox. not the actual checkbox.

Comment: then you can do it using jquery or javascript

Comment: @SpiderCode the `+ label` part works just fine for targeting an adjacent element

Answer (score 0):

use

```
 <input type="checkbox" class="check1" />
<label class="label1">test Label</label>

.check1:checked + .label1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mL5dC/)

Answer (score 0):

Note that this does not work in IE 6-8, being a later feature. It will however work in IE9, just remember to include a doctype, or it won't.

HTML

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" class="checklabel" />
  <label class="label">Your Label</label>
<div>
```

CSS

```
.checklabel:checked + .label {
  color: purple; 
}
```

Just add the on-checked CSS above.

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {  }
```

Other way:

HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check1" />
<label class="label1">Your Label</label>
```

CSS

```
.check1:checked + .label1 {
  background-color: #ff5819;
}
```

**[See demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CFvNs/)**

pseudo-class **:checked** is not supported in IE 6-8. ([See here](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-checked))
So use selectivizr http://selectivizr.com/.

**selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest.**

Usage of selectivizr

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[JS library]"></script>
<!--[if (gte IE 6)&(lte IE 8)]>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="selectivizr.js"></script>
  <noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="[fallback css]" /></noscript>
<![endif]-->
```